# The server runs the spring boot project, and some pages cannot be loaded normally

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

The springboot project contains a front-end page - FuncPepStatistics. The content of this page is composed of statistical graphs generated by js code written by echarts.js.
After the project is run in idea, the FuncPepStatistics.html page can be run successfully.
However, if the springboot project is packaged, whether it is run on the local cmd or on the cloud server, the page cannot be successfully displayed, and the error that occurs is a 500 type error
The console of the browser gives the following error:
`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 () Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received`
The server terminal error is as follows:

```
[THYMELEAF][http-nio-9188-exec-9] Exception processing template "/FuncPepStatistics": Error resolving template [/FuncPepStatistics], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/FuncPepStatistics], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/mfppdb] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/FuncPepStatistics], template might not might exist not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [/FuncPepStatistics], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

I have checked that the application.properties file configuration is correct, there is no error in the path, and the view function is also correct.

Comment: The problem has been solved. The solution comes from: spring-boot-thymeleaf-not-resolving-fragments-after-packaging